# Video Indexer [Update connection to Azure Media Services]

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

In the Video Indexer, I am having trouble connecting it with Azure Media Service.
In the image below, I have type my Account Subscription ID, the Resource Group Name, for the Application ID and Application key I am not very sure because it was not indicated in the steps of the Microsoft Documentations, click [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/connect-to-azure#create-and-configure-a-media-services-account) to access the documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The application ID and application key are the Service Principal Azure AD app and secret to access the Media Services account.
See this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/access-api-howto?tabs=portal

Comment: I believe that the Service Principal Azure AD App and secret are these two, see [link](https://imgur.com/pbMXmJy) for image? I have tried to input them but I get an error "General Error", see [link](https://imgur.com/kn02fBt) for image